# How to catch html response in Java?

Tags: java, html, servlet-filters

I'm going to get Html responses and  do some modifications on responses in Java before they reach client.
My idea is writing a servlet-filter but I don't know how to implement that.
What I got is :`javax.servlet.ServletResponse resp` and `javax.servlet.ServletRequest req`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The essentials of filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)
check the part on modifying responses

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet filter, you can provide your own subclass of [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html)

After the call of chain.doFilter(...), your response wrapper will contain the html content, you'll be able to retrieve and transform it.
You can find a similar servlet filter there as example : http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/filters.html

Answer (score 0):

use `head first`'s chapter for filter there is an example of `HttpServletResponseWrapper`. very nice book for servlet and jsp s.